# Context Menu - Align some text left, and some text right

Tags: java, javafx

I have a context menu in my program. I would like to show the keys that perform the same function as the context menu. I would like to have the name of the menu left justified, and the key command right justified. I don't have a screenshot, but here is a drawing:

**How things are now (Simplified)**

```
Play (↵)
Stop (X)
Enqueue (Q)
Browse Folder (B)
```

**How I'd like things to be**

```
Play           (↵)
Stop           (X)
Enqueue        (Q)
Browse Folder  (B)
```

My code is just boilerplate javafx context menu code:

```
    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem playMenuItem = new MenuItem( "Play (↵)" );
    MenuItem queueMenuItem = new MenuItem( "Enqueue (Q)" );
    MenuItem cropMenuItem = new MenuItem( "Crop (⇧␡)" );
    MenuItem deleteMenuItem = new MenuItem( "Delete (␡)" );
    MenuItem browseMenuItem = new MenuItem( "Browse Folder (B)" );
```

Is there any way to put two labels on a context menu, or have one float some text right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can avoid this problem completely by using accelerators. (Which is what those are meant for I guese?) For example:

```
 ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
 MenuItem playMenuItem = new MenuItem( "Play" );
 playMenuItem.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER));
 //etc.
```

This wil not only take care of the acceleration for you, but it will also display the acceleration keys in a simular way you are trying to achieve at the moment with plain Strings.

Comment: It even uses the same utf symbol for enter. . :-D Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why KeyCode.ENTER isn't working on a tableview context menu? The rest work, but Enter will not unless I combine it with something like CONTROL_DOWN or SHIFT_DOWN.

Comment: Thats propably because its used by the tableView Node in its default behavior (but I have no clue what for). Maybe its in the javadoc somewhere, and otherwise you could check its BehaviorSkin to see for what exactually.